# How to receive notification faster, like whats app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, whatsapp

Like whats app, If I turn on the internet connection as soon as the device is connected to internet first notification I receive is from whats app then other applications notification, How can i achieve this

Comment: you can set **android:priority** attribute to your internet receiver

Answer (score 1):

Whats app uses XMPP for this but you can use MQTT for this as it is simple to integrate and is reliable